# how to replace all lines between two points and subtitute it with some text in sed

Tags: linux, sed

Suppose I have this text:

```
BEGIN
hello
world
how
are
you
END
```

How to convert it to bellow text using sed command in linux:

```
BEGIN
fine, thanks
END
```

Answer (score 40):

```
$ cat file
BEGIN
hello
world
how
are
you
END

$ sed -e '/BEGIN/,/END/c\BEGIN\nfine, thanks\nEND' file
BEGIN
fine, thanks
END
```

`/BEGIN/,/END/` selects a range of text that starts with `BEGIN` and ends with `END`. Then `c\` command is used to replace the selected range with `BEGIN\nfine, thanks\nEND`.

Comment: Some explanation what sed techniques where used would be nice

Comment: Amazing and easy to understand, worked great for me - thanks!