# Replacing the lines between two commented lines using sed commands in a java file

Tags: bash, sed

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I need to replace this section of code in java (using JDK-8) file using sed commands -

```
//START_EDIT1
some lines
//END_EDIT1
```

with this lines of codes.

```
//START_EDIT1
System.out.println("Done");
//END_EDIT1
```

I am a newbie and can not find the right commands to find this two comments in java code and replace the code between them using sed commands.I can not change the java comment format. Is there a way to find this using sed commands? or simply what is the sed command to find double forward slash comment?

Comment: So, all the text between start & end markers it to be deleted & to be replaced by `System.out.println("Done");` ?

Comment: is it asked to replace the code? that's weird....

Comment: Sir, sorry for bad language. I am just asking how to find the lines between those comments using sed command. @TomN

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5178828/3776858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/\/\/START_EDIT1/,/\/\/END_EDIT1/c\//START_EDIT1\nSystem.out.println("Done");\n//END_EDIT1' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: you could also you a different delimiter for better readability.. `sed '\@//START_EDIT1@,\@//END_EDIT1@ c\//START_EDIT1\nSystem.out.println("Done");\n//END_EDIT1' file`

Comment: Thanks to both Cyrus  and @ritesht93 :D .

Answer (score 0):

Why cant do you a vi  and  ESC  `:%s/START_EDIT1/System.out.println\(\"Done\"\)\;/g`
again for `:%s/END_EDIT1//g`

You could achieve the samething with sed as well. But this has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Sir, sorry. I am actually trying to achieve this using sed command. I was failing using diffrent sed commands and was not sure about its relation to java file. Thats why I tagged java. I corrected the tag in the post. @Raghu K  Nair