# Linux: How to replace all text between two lines and substitute it with the output of a variable using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a problem that is very similar to this SO thread: [how to replace all lines between two points and subtitute it with some text in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178828/how-to-replace-all-lines-between-two-points-and-subtitute-it-with-some-text-in-s)

Consider a problem like this:

```
$ cat file
BEGIN
hello
world
how
are
you
END

$ sed -e '/BEGIN/,/END/c\BEGIN\nfine, thanks\nEND' file
BEGIN
fine, thanks
END
```

How might I inject text that I have saved to a variable like:

```
str1=$(echo "This is a test")
```

How can I inject str1's output in the place of `fine, thanks`, like:

```
sed -e '/BEGIN/,/END/c\BEGIN\n$str1\nEND' file  # fails to work as hoped
```

I also want to save the output to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -e '/BEGIN/,/END/ {//!d; /BEGIN/r file.html' -e '}' file
```

This will insert content of `file.html` file between `BEGIN` and `END`. To save changes back to file:

```sh
sed -i -e '/BEGIN/,/END/ {//!d; /BEGIN/r file.html' -e '}' file
```

Comment: Quick question in case you are still monitoring -- how to add a return `\n` to this such that there is a clear line break between the BEGIN and END?

Comment: Try: `sed -e '/BEGIN/,/END/ {//!d; /BEGIN/r file.html' -e ';s/^/\n/;}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Sure is easy in `awk`.

Given:

```
cat file
ABC
BEGIN
hello
world
how
are
you
END
XYZ
```

You can do:

```
str='TEST'

awk -v r="$str" -v f=1 '/^BEGIN$/{print $0 "\n" r; f=0}
/^END$/{f=1} f' file
```

Prints:

```
ABC
BEGIN
TEST
END
XYZ
```

---

If you want to embed another file in between those marks:

```
awk -v f=1 -v fn='ur_file' '/^BEGIN$/{
    print $0
    while ((getline<fn)>0) {print}
    f=0}
/^END$/{f=1} f' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the input -- this gives me an error, however:
`-bash: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long` as I have to paste quite a lot of text in.

Comment: An alternative is to do like: `awk -v r="cat file.html ...`;  but then I want to write the work awk does to the file.